# Can I break the rules and use firebase-admin on the client side? Or will trying to workaround errors be for nothing?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-admin

Wanting to create a system admin page for my Firebase project, is there any way I can break the rules and use the firebase-admin SDK on a client side browser?

The first problem I ran into was using the firebase/database SDK after successfully initialising with the admin initializeApp function, I got the error "TypeError: rtdb.initStandalone is not a function". Should I carry on trying to work around this, or come at it with a different angle. Ideally I would prefer not to have to use calls to the server, or use firebase auth with a 'superuser' privilege.

Answer (score 6):

The Firebase Admin SDK should only be run in a privileged environment, like your server or [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions). It provides direct administrative access that is not secure on the client.

> The Admin SDK lets you interact with Firebase from privileged environments to perform actions like:
>
> - Read and write Realtime Database data with full admin privileges.
> - Programmatically send Firebase Cloud Messaging messages using a simple, alternative approach to the FCM server protocols.
> - Generate and verify Firebase auth tokens.
> - Access Google Cloud Platform resources like Cloud Storage buckets and Firestore databases associated with your Firebase projects.
> - Create your own simplified admin console to do things like look up user data or change a user's email address for authentication.
>
> If you are interested in using the Node.js SDK as a client for end-user access (for example, in a Node.js desktop or IoT application), as opposed to admin access from a privileged environment (like a server), you should instead follow the [instructions for setting up the client JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup).